# .htaccess equivalent in Node.js to add password protection to my web application

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, passport.js

Is it possible to add an **.htaccess(or similar)** or a **Password protection** to my main api routes in Node.js app or MEAN app without re-configuring the api routes and middlewares I created using express.

> This Node.js app already contains multiple passport.js strategies or authentication for user management such as (passport.local, passport.oauth2.0, passport.facebook) so adding another passport strategy might messed up my **req.session.user** data.

I just want to make my web app private for Staging without re-configuring my API-routes because it already contains different types of authentication.

**PS: I'm sorry for my bad english. I don't know how to properly ask this question.**

Note: The Node.js app is hosted in Amazon Ec2. The file storage are on Amazon S3.

Comment: I don't think `passport` and `.htaccess` play the same rule. `passport` is used for user management while i think `.htaccess` is used to protect certain `path` or `directory`. What exactly is your requirement. Can you make it more clear.

Comment: I want to make my app private for staging. I've tried using basic-auth module for making my site private and it did not affect my other express routes but I worry it's not safe (site does not run on HTTPS yet). 

I'm sorry, maybe I misunderstood htaccess for making a site private. Thank you for your response.